# Generate JAX-WS client abstract interface from wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf, webservice-client

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the CXF and JAX-WS, I want to know if I can generate abstract interface code based on the `WSDL` so that I can implement a web service client based on the interface. Better to give me some tutorial or helpful post to read . Thanks.

Comment: You are aware of "wsimport" in the JDK?

Comment: +1 Never heard about it. :)  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
 % wsimport -p destinationDirectory -keep  http://localhost:8888/YourWSDL?wsdl
```

wsimport comes with core java 6